# How to set apache permissions for a Postgresql in Ubuntu for a Django project?

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, web-deployment

Ok so I did not set apache permissions for db.sqlite3 as I intend to use postgresql, but I did give permission to my whole  django project folder.

Now, should I just make a postgresql user and a db and assign the credentials in the settings.py and leave it like that? Also, I'm not really sure what to put in the "HOST" and "PORT" entries if that's the case?

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": 'mydbname_db',
        "USER": 'myuser',
        "PASSWORD": 'mypass',
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": "",
    }
}
```